# How to pass data into a <a> tag like link_to rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to transform this ruby link_to method into a classic  tag. And before i'd use to pass some value (idz) into the parse after the link tag.

Is it possible to do the same with  tags. Is because I need this value (idz) to run my controller method

Before :

```
<%= link_to rem_admin_group_path(group, idz: admin.id), method: :patch, remote: true do %>
  <div class="btn btn-danger pull-right"style='margin-left: 10px;'>
    <i class="fa fa-close" aria-hidden="true" ></i>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

After (without the value idz):

```
<a href="groups/<%=group.id%>/rem_admin",  data-method="patch" data-remote="true">
  <div class="btn btn-danger pull-right"style='margin-left: 10px;'>
    <i class="fa fa-close" aria-hidden="true" ></i>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: pretty sure you can use the rails method `url_for`
https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/RoutingUrlFor/url_for

Comment: What you mean ? The first one (link_to) instead of transform it ?

Comment: yup, take a look at the examples in the link I attached

Comment: you should do like this :`<%= link_to 'Project Request', new_request_path(project: true) %>`
which would produce a link like http://127.0.0.1:3000/request?project=true

Comment: How does your definition for `rem_admin_group_path` in your `config/routes.rb` look like?

Comment: If I follow my url path, it's something like this

 <a href="groups/<%=group.id%>/rem_admin?idz=#{admin.id}",  data-method="patch" data-remote="true">

But is not working like that

Comment: Rails just outputs HTML. Look at your markup, find the `<a>` tag you're generating, and copy it. Sub in your dynamic values for the static values exactly like you're doing with `<%= group.id %>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
<a href="groups/<%=group.id%>/rem_admin?idz=<%=admin.id%>",  data-method="patch" data-remote="true">
  <div class="btn btn-danger pull-right"style='margin-left: 10px;'>
    <i class="fa fa-close" aria-hidden="true" ></i>
  </div>
</a>
```